# What's so well in having a least element in a set?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

What's so well about the principle of well-ordering? Why is this pattern of order named like this? I am unable to trace a connection between well-ordering and a set that has a least element so I presume that there must be some mathematical becakground I'm unaware of. I've searched some wikipedia links but they describe only what the principle is, not the reason why it's named like this.

Comment: What do you mean by *a connection between ... least element*? By definition a linear order $\le$ on a set $X$ is a well-ordering of $X$ iff each non-empty $A\subseteq X$ has a $\le$-least element.

Comment: I've read only a naive definition of the involved concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Cantor was led to introduce the basic concepts of set theory (especially ordinal an cardinal numbers) by the need for transfinite inductive definitions in treating some aspects of trigonometric series.  So it's not surprising that he should call a set well-ordered (wohlgeordnet) when it serves his purpose of supporting transfinite inductions.

Answer (score 6):

It's a good order to do induction over, because we always know what's next. If you are given a bounded subset, you know what the "next step".

Therefore you can perform induction over a linear order when it is well-ordered. That's good, that's very well.

(Another analogy is to a line to the bathroom. If the line is well-ordered everybody knows their place, and whoever wants to get in line knows exactly where they need to stand, and no one can cut in line. If the line is ordered like the rational numbers then everything is dense and people can cut in line wherever they feel like it, but no one is moving along anyway! That's not very good.)

Other than that, don't put too much emphasis on the actual name. Focus on the definition itself, it's much better.

Comment: Yeah - I'm not really worried with it's name. I was just courious on why this concept was named like this.

Comment: Well, technically, they need not know who is after them (each element in a well-ordered set need not have an immediate predecessor).

Comment: @Tobias: Even if $\omega$ doesn't know who is exactly before him, he still knows who is before him. And knows exactly who is right after him. So no one can cut in line!

Comment: But in any total ordering we know precisely who is both before and after us. It is the immediate before/after that is important here (and we only have one of them).

Comment: @Tobias: Fine. I changed the analogy a little bit.

Comment: I think the suitability for induction is the key reason for the "well".  Compare [well-founded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded).

Comment: @MJD: I think that well-founded relations were investigated after the concept of well-ordered was established as sufficient for induction, and well-founded relations were the obvious generalization that still allowed induction.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a name, I wouldn't spend too much time pondering it.

It's not totally arbitrary though - for example, choosing the minimal element of a subset of some set $X$ is well-*defined* exactly if $X$ is well-*ordered*. Similarly, an inductively defined function is well-*defined* only if the domain is well-*ordered*.

Comment: I know it's just a name. But someone somewhere may have thought: "Hey! This mathematical pattern is well because of X" - I want to know what's the X.

Comment: Than I'd say it's *well* because it allows inductive definitions and because it allows you to pick elements from subsets. The latter might seem trivial, but it's not. To be able to *generally* pick elements from an arbitrary number of sets, one needs the axiom of choice which, here it comes, is equivalent to every set being well-orderable.